# Ubuntu Server 16.04 unable to get virtualbox running

Tags: virtualbox, 16.04

Cannot get vboxweb-service to start for phpvirtualbox.  Many changes to where the initialization and services go.  Basically, I'm dead in the water trying to establish a Ubuntu 16.04 virtualbox host.  Is there a clear method to install virtualbox and phpvirtualbox in server 16.04 (no gui)?

Comment: If you are going to down-vote, please comment why.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small script that work with Ubuntu 14.04 as well as Ubuntu 15.x and Ubuntu 16.04. It install all the packages, so phpvirtualbox runs. Download the script (https://github.com/joergre/workshops/blob/master/LF6/vb.py) and give him rights to "chmod a + x vb.py". Then start the program with ./vb.py
Then it takes a moment and everything should work. Please change the password in line 8. Login then IP/phpvirtualbox and username/password admin/admin.

Have a nice day